# Display the JSON data returned from PHP in the Datatable format

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I am new to JQUERY and I am trying to search for the something and based on the searched text I am doing an ajax call which will call php function and the PHP is returning me with JSON data.
I want to display the returned data in the Datatable form.
I have my PHP file table.php and JavaScript file jss.js and my main.php.
The PHP file is returning the JSON data and I able to use alert to display it.

I want to know how can I display it in datatable.

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" placeholder="Search Client" size="50" autocomplete="off"/>
<button  id="search" name="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

my ajax/jss.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').click(function(){
        var search_query = $('#search_query').val();


        if(search_query !='')
        {       
            $.ajax({
                url:"table.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{search_query:search_query},

                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert("HEKKI "+data);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please Search again");
        }
    });
});
```

my table.php file

```
<?php
    $data=array();
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','acdc') OR die('Could not connect because: '.mysqli_connect_error());

        if (isset($_REQUEST['search_query'])) 
        {
            $name = $_REQUEST['search_query'];
        }


        if($dbc)
        {

            if (!empty($name)) 
            {
                $sql = "select  c.res1      res1, 
                                cc.res2     res2, 
                                cc.res3     res3, 
                                cc.res4     res4, 
                                cc.res5     res5 
                        from table1 c 
                        inner join table2 cc
                        on c.id = cc.id
                        where c.name like '".$name."%'
                        and cc.ENABLED = 1";

                $res = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);


                if(!(mysqli_num_rows($res)==0))
                {
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                        $data['RES1']   =   $row['res1'];
                        $data['RES2']   =   $row['res2'];
                        $data['RES3']   =   $row['res3'];
                        $data['RES4']   =   $row['res4'];
                        $data['RES5']   =   $row['res5'];
                    }
                }

                else

                {
                    echo "<div style='display: block; color:red; text-align:center'><br/> Not Found,Please try again!!!</div>";
                }
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($data);

        /*

    */

    ?>
```

Can you please guide me how to display the result in main page.

Comment: can yo include the `JSON` structure or sample returned?  It appears to me that your `PHP` is only returning a single object `{RES1: 'res1', RES2: 'res2, etc...'}`

Comment: @Steve Yes you are right. JSON is returning single data. Can you please help me how to get all data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting utf8 as charset is probably a good idea. If you have different charset in your table you will get a JSON error :

```php
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
```

Then use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`. You want `field: value` records turned into JSON :

```php
$data = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   $data[] = $row;
}
```

Output the JSON :

```php
echo json_encode( array('data' => $data) );
```

Now you can use it directly along with dataTables  :

```html
<table id="example"></table>
```

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: 'table.php'
  },
  columns: [
    { data: 'res1', title: 'res1'},
    { data: 'res2', title: 'res2'},
    //etc..
  ]
})
```

Comment: it worked but when the search is done again without refreshing the page, it says "Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3"

Comment: @SodruldeenMustapha, use [**destroy: true**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) if you need to reinitialise the DataTable ...

Answer (score 0):

one approach is to create the form fulfiled with data just in `table.php` file and with support of jQuery you will need to populate the `<form id="form_id">` with ajax result `$('#form_id').html(ajax_response);`

other aproach:
to use jQuery json data to populate every field separately.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse( ajax_response ); // decode json
```

than

```
$('#id_input_1').val(jsonData.RES1);
$('#id_input_2').val(jsonData.RES2);
$('#id_input_3').val(jsonData.RES3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a `placeholder` in this case I used `#results`, and dynamically create a table and append it to the `placeholder`.  I commented out your ajax for this example, but just call the `function` I created to process the results from within the `success` callback and pass the new `function` a javascript object.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').click(function() {
    var search_query = $('#search_query').val();


    if (search_query != '') {
      //$.ajax({
      //  url: "table.php",
      //  method: "POST",
      //  data: {
      //    search_query: search_query
      //  },

      //  success: function(data) {
      //    alert("HEKKI " + data);
      //  }
      //});
      processResults({RES1: "result1", RES2: "result2"});
    } else {
      alert("Please Search again");
    }
  });
});
function processResults(obj){
  var $tbl = $("<table>");
  var $row = $("<tr>");
  var trow;
  $.each(obj, function(idx, elem){
    trow = $row.clone();
    trow.append($("<td>" + obj[idx] + "</td>"));
    $tbl.append(trow);
  });
  $("#results").append($tbl);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" placeholder="Search Client" size="50" autocomplete="off" />
  <button id="search" name="submit">Search</button>
  <div id='results'></div>
</div>
```